# Constructing an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(6) \to (\mathbb{Z}/(7)^{\times})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

On our exam today, one of the problems was to construct an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(6) \to ((\mathbb{Z}/(7))^{\times})$ where both groups are viewed under multiplication. My first instinct was to just use

$$
\varphi(a) = a + 1 \ (\text{mod $7$})
$$

but I'm having a hard time showing that this a homomorphism (I don't think it even is). Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: I'm sorry -- we only view $((\mathbb{Z}/(7))^{\times})$ as a group under multiplication

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $0$ must go to $1$ (why?) , then find out where to send $1$ (hint: consider its order).
If you found out where to send $1$ then we just build our function $f$ into an homomorphism:
$f(2) = f(1+1) = f(1) + f(1)$

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's not a homomorphism, merely a bijection.  Since one group is additive, and the other is multiplicative, you should not expect to solve this without thinking about multiplication somehow.

In general, the way to construct a homomorphism from a cyclic group is to specify where the generator goes.  For example, choosing a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\to G$ is the same as choosing an element $g\in G$ with $g^6=1$.  This map is an injection precisely when $g$ has order $6$.

In other words, the problem boils down to this: Can you find an element of $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$ with (multiplicative) order $6$?